# where is the git config credential.helper value coming from?

Tags: git, git-config, git-credential-manager

I have multiple git repositories

On some repositories `git config credential.helper` returns `manager` while on others it returns `helper-selector`.

Where are these different values configured?
It does not exist in the `.git/config` file.

Comment: There is also the global config file. `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: there is no global config file in the usual locations. Is there a command to know where the config is located like maybe `git config --get-location credential.helper`?